# Showing that the floor is an integer

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Say you define $\lfloor x \rfloor := \sup\{y \in \mathbb{Z}~|~y \leq x\}$. How do you show that $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is an integer, i.e. that the supremum is a member of the set $\{y \in \mathbb{Z}~|~y \leq x\}$?

Comment: The supremum of a set is inside the closure of that set.  $\mathbb Z$ is a closed set inside of the reals, subsets of $\mathbb Z$ are closed, and the supremum of that subset must be in the subset.

Comment: It follows from $\mathbb Z$ being a closed subset of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: That’s clean, but I’m wondering if we can show this manually, without appealing to topological facts?

Comment: I mean to say, something a first-week real analysis student can understand.

Comment: Does a first-week real analysis student know what a supremum is? In any case you only have to show that a subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ which is bounded above has a greatest element and this is very easy, e.g. it is more or less equivalent to induction.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I see, thank you.

Comment: @coffeemath Fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove this, you must use some property of the real number system, as there are other ordered fields for which this [supremum may not exist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Archimedean_ordered_field#Applications).

Let $S=\{y\in \mathbb Z\mid y\leq x\}$.

Now if integers $a<b$ and $b\in S$ then certainly $a\in S$, so either $S=\emptyset$, $S=\mathbb Z$, or $$S=\{z\in \mathbb Z\mid z\leq n\}$$ for some $n$. (This could be proved by induction as Qiaochu Yuan suggests in the comments.)

The [Archimedean property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property) of the reals guarantees $S$ is nonempty and not all of $\mathbb Z$, and therefore has a maximum element $n$.  But a maximum element of a subset is always the supremum, since $n$ is clearly an upper bound and if $r<n$ then $r$ is not an upper bound for $S$.

#### Remark

You could in fact show directly that the existence of a supremum for $S$, in any ordered field, is already enough to guarantee $S$ cannot be $\mathbb Z$ or $\emptyset$, without further appealing to the Archimedean property, but this proof would be quite similar to the proof of the Archimedean property itself from the LUB property.